# Java propery way to delete an Integer from ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, autoboxing

I have an array list of integers and would like to delete an Integer value from it. To clarify: Let's say I have a function that takes in an `ArrayList` of Integers, and specified Integer value. I need to return the list with (value+1) deleted from it.

`boolean deleteFromList(ArrayList<Integer> list, Integer value)`

Now, if I do this:

```
return list.remove(value+1)
```

compiler will complain because it will try to invoke the delete method that takes `int` parameter and deletes an object from specified location, not the actual object.
So what is a proper way to deal with this? Is it better to do:

```
list.remove((Integer)(value+1))
```

or

```
int v = value.intValue();
v++;
list.remove(new Integer(v));
```

? In the second case, can I be sure the right value will be deleted?

Comment: sorry, the correct method name is remove, I was writing it from the top of my head. I will update my question

Comment: @Maroun `list.remove(v+1)` doesn't work - that's the whole point.

Comment: I think this is an opinion-based question, so I have voted to close.  You have already discovered that `remove((Integer)(value+1))` and `remove(new Integer(value+1))` both work.  As for which is better - just pick whichever makes you happier.

Comment: are they the same in terms of autoboxing/boxing? will one take longer than the other? will it produce unnecessary objects?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I expect that `remove((Integer)(value+1))` and `remove(new Integer(value+1))` would probably produce identical byte code.

Comment: and after reading the answers, and some Javadocs, I realise that my last two comments were both wrong!!  The byte code won't be identical for the two snippets in my last comment.  This is NOT an opinion-based question at all - there is a good reason for not using `new Integer(...)`.  Some of the answers explain the reason.  I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the second case, can I be sure the right value will be deleted?

Yes you can.

The `remove` method will use `equals(Object)` to identify the object to be removed from the list.  Since `Integer.equals` compares by value (not by object identity), it doesn't matter how you created the `Integer` instances ... provided the wrapped `int` values are the same.

---

However ... your second version is inferior to the first version:

- It cumbersome: 3 statements instead of 1.
- You are using `new Integer(...)` rather than `Integer.valueOf(...)` which is always going to create a new instance.  By contrast, autoboxing (or calling `Integer.valueOf(...)` explicitly) makes use of the `Integer` classes instance cache, and that will often avoid creating a new instance.

Comment: Moreover, comparing Integer instance is inefficient since it is done with equals() which will need to test the instance class (instanceof), cast and finally access members.

Comment: @sebtic - If you've decided to use a `java.util.Collection` class, that overhead is unavoidable.  While there are other alternatives that are more efficient, they have definite drawbacks as well.  Hence, I'm not prepared to recommend to the OP to switch to a 3rd party list-of-integers class.  It might be a good idea ... or it might not ... depending on the circumstances.

Comment: @StephenC I completely agree but everyone must keep in mind that boxing/unboxing is easy and versatile but can have huge drawbacks and pitfalls. Often, a better modeling resolves the problems by itself and more efficiently but it greatly depends on what can be changed.

Comment: @sebtic - 1) You forget that the requirement to use a Collection type often comes from the APIs you are using.  2) This is not about modelling (in the design sense, e.g. UML).  It is about mapping the design model to concrete implementation types.

Answer (score 2):

`list.remove(value+1)` will remove at given index.

You can use `list.remove(Integer.valueOf(value+1))` to remove the `Integer`.

`Integer.valueOf(v)` is recommanded instead of `new Integer(v)` because it allows reuse of `Integer` instances for special values (see javadoc).

EDIT :
In term of boxing/unboxing, it is possible to completely eliminate the problem using libraries like trove4j which define an dynamic array of integer storing the primitive values instead of numeric class (see [TIntArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html)). No boxing, no unboxing, lower GC use and better performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(value+1));
```

should work fine.

Comment: yes, it will work. But I am interested in a bit of analysis what happens in terms of boxing and autoboxing. which way is more efficient and elegant to use?

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for this one.

```
Collections.sort(list);
int index = list.indexOf(5);
list = list.subList(0, index-1);
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list.indexOf(value + 1) since that method only takes the object. Then use that index to remove the element.

```
    int i = list.indexOf(value + 1);
    list.remove(i);
```

If you need to remove all instances of value + 1 then continue until i is -1 (not found).

Or, just iterate over it and remove as you find them

```
    for (Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Integer integer = iterator.next();
        if (integer == value + 1) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A more effective way might be to use a `TIntArrayList` from [Trove4j](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TIntArrayList.html) library which wraps `int[]` array and doesn't use wrapper types. For this reason it takes 3x times less memory and is much faster.

Comment: It is TIntArrayList not TIntArray